# Vertical dashed line does not connect on top when using \multicolumn and arydshln

Tags: tables

I am trying to include a dashed line in the middle of a table but it cuts off before connecting to the top line. I will include the code to better explain it. How do I make the dashed line connect to the horizontal line on top?

```
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{tabular}{lr;{1pt/1pt}lr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Bold text}} \\ \midrule
main info & 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{side info}} \\
\cdashline{3-4}[1pt/1pt]
main info & 2 & A & 0 \\
main info & 3 & B & 1 \\
main info & 4 & C & 2 \\
main info & 5 & D & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Maybe reducing vertical space helps (wait for another good suggestions btw).

Comment: They can't connect: the rules from `booktabs` add some vertical padding above and below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work-around: I set the padding of the rules from booktabs to `0pt` (locally), and replaced it with a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`  (if you use `siunitx`, use the prefix `C` instead). This uses package `cellspace`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}t
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{arydshln, booktabs}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{Slr;{1pt/1pt}lr}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{Sc}{\textbf{Bold text}} \\ \midrule
main info & 1 & \multicolumn{2}{Sc}{\textbf{side info}} \\
\cdashline{3-4}[1pt/1pt]
main info & 2 & A & 0 \\
main info & 3 & B & 1 \\
main info & 4 & C & 2 \\
main info & 5 & D & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this works but somehow loading cellspace ruined other tables in the document.

Comment: ??? Do you load `siunitx`?

Comment: I was but even after I removed it still the same. It seems that there are some conflicts with column type p as only those tables are affected when I load cellspace.

Comment: I never met such a problem with `cellspace`. In which sense did it ruin other tables? Also, could you post a minimal complete example reproducing  the problem?